# URL regenerate in magento 2

Tags: php, magento, seo

I am developing my website in Magento 2, I need URL regenerate for products after I changed the category URL.

URL's are not changing for existing products.

Ex:

Category URL's:
New URL:
 http://test.com/jewellery-collections/gold-jewellery/gold-rings
Old URL:
 http://test.com/collections/gold/rings

Product URL's:
 http://test.com/collections/gold/rings/midas-bloom

but the URL should be 
 http://test.com/jewellery-collections/gold-jewellery/gold-ringsmidas-bloom

So, Product URL's should be regenerate as per new category URL

Answer (score -1):

A quite simple solution is to use a ready to run Magento 2 module which does exactly the work of an rewrite indexer. You can call this regeneration by code or from command line. A better solution is to do it by code in your own importer module. The regeneration is quite simple

```
foreach($list as $product) {
if($store_id === Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID)
    $product->setStoreId($store_id);
$this->urlPersist->deleteByData([
    UrlRewrite::ENTITY_ID => $product->getId(),
    UrlRewrite::ENTITY_TYPE => ProductUrlRewriteGenerator::ENTITY_TYPE,
    UrlRewrite::REDIRECT_TYPE => 0,
    UrlRewrite::STORE_ID => $store_id
]);
try {
    $this->urlPersist->replace(
        $this->productUrlRewriteGenerator->generate($product)
    );
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    $out->writeln('<error>Duplicated url for '. $product->getId() .'</error>');
} }
```

As you can see Magento 2 offers you a model for regenerate url rewrites \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlRewriteGenerator (productUrlRewriteGenerator) which you can inject into your model. This generated url rewrite can be replaced by \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlPersistInterface (urlPersist). You can run this in a loop for all products after import or for each single product after a change.

Or you can check out https://github.com/Iazel/magento2-regenurl